# can a file path be used as a variable input in terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to use the project name from the path as an input to main.tf.
For example I have the file path as follows

```
/env/nonprod/overlay/prj-npe-02/main.tf
```

and in my main.tf can the input var.project_name be taken from the file path which is "../prj-npe-02/.."

```
main.tf
data "google_project" "project" {
    project_id = var.project_name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar to Hannes answer but I used regex to arrive at the solution

```
data "google_project" "project" {
    project_id = regex( "prj-[^\\/]+", abspath(path.root))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using the split and abspath function.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/abspath

```
locals {
  absolute_path = abspath(path.root)
  project_id    = split("/", local.absolute_path)[3]
}


output "name" {
  value = local.project_id
}
```

Just tested on my end and works like a charm.

If you want to adapt to your resource, it should look like this.

```
data "google_project" "project" {
    project_id = local.project_id
}
```